# Appcelerator startup error

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Appcelerator was working fine on my computer. I needed to free up some disk space so I used Windows' Disk Cleanup tool to delete temporary files. Since then, I'm getting the following error when I try to login to my account in Appcelerator,

[Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgVQL.png)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything but that didn't solve the problem. It's getting very frustrating. Please help!

Comment: Did you try to login using command-line using this command - appc login ?

It has always helped me in login issues.

Comment: Yes, and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean uninstall CLI then reinstall it. You can check out the following blog links

- http://titaniumsolution.blogspot.com/2017/01/clean-uninstall-then-reinstall-cli-to.html
- http://titaniumsolution.blogspot.com/2016/12/fresh-installation-appcelerator-studio.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your node and npm version.